# I am trying to run a simple "Hello World" in C++ using VSCode, but it shows : "The term g++ is not recognizedas the name of cmdlet, and so on.."

Tags: c++, g++

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main () {
    cout << "Hello World";
    return 0;
}
```

And when I try to run it, it shows this:

> g++ : The term 'g++' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.

Can anyone tell me what I did wrong? Or is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Have you installed g++?

Comment: I haven't, and that's also one of the reasons why I'm here. Can you show me the link/command to install g++

Comment: There are countless introductions to getting started with C++ in VS Code online. Use a search engine, or follow the links on the official site to find [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw) step-by-step guide.

Comment: There are two options to get g++, MinGW or MinGW64, the latter a fork of the former for compiling 64 bit applications and libraries (and appears even more advanced to me now).